# storemi / enmotus - how to recover data in this tier

Tags: windows, partition-recovery, amd-ryzen

AS Rock B450 Pro 4
Ryzen 2600

I had a storemi setup with a bootable tier.

SSD1 (fast)
HDD1 (slow)

something odd happened to my windows, not sure what, causing it to become unusable. I pulled a working SSD (SSD2) from my laptop and wanted to achieve the following

SSD1 (boot non-tier)

SSD2 (fast)
HDD1 (slow)

the plan is to detach SSD1 from tier, format new windows on it and then make a tier out of SSD2 and HDD1 while keeping the data.
so i booted up SSD2 (it already had windows installed) installed storemi and opted to "Remove fast media".
This seemed to go ok and now the SSD1 is no longer part of the storemi tier.
When i laucnh StoreMI app, however, all that happens is all options are blanked out and i only have  "change settings" available to me.
[image: [only option]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKb8i.png)

Inside of change settings only the HDD1 is avail to select. [image: [hdd1 select]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYT9n.png)

If i select it and In here it is still "Tier Full" mode.
[image: Tier full only]

If i attempt to change it to single, I end up with an error "error converting tier to single mode" and the application kills itself.

I tried running the enmotus CLI software directly to get additional info but its a little over my head and I don't really have the time to dig into this.

```
PS C:\Program Files\AMD\StoreMI\ECmd> ecmd --status
Host MicroTiering Engine, Version 1.3.46A4.19502
  Tiered Disks        : 1 (1 max)
  Physical Disks      : 1 total, 1 used (2 max)
  Global Tiering      : Enabled
  Time Running        : 0d:0h:18m:36s
  Global Scan Period  : 2 seconds
  Total Capacity      : 0 B/32 TiB (Available: 32 TiB)
  Fast Capacity       : 0 B/256 GiB (Available: 256 GiB)
  Page Map Memory     : 0 MBytes (0 KBytes)
  Default Page Size   : 4M

Host Luns:
 ID ST TYPE      NAME     PRODUCTID        SIZE     SECT RAM   FAST  RSVD  PAGE
                                           GiB      SIZE CACHE PAGES PAGES SIZE
 ==============================================================================

tDrives:
 ID ST NAME             SIZE  M   VD   IN PLCY ----------- PROMOTE --------
                        GiB                      THR NEW     COUNT      PPS DIV
 ==============================================================================
 0  KO T00 StoreMI      1861  T  ff, 0 RL RDIO    0  0       0           32  0
 ^-- Promotes are turned off

vDrives:
 ID ST CFG T  D  SECTORS     SECTORS     SIZE     M  STR RQ CONFIG
                 AVAIL       CONFIG      GiB
 ======================================================================
 0  0  2   0  0  e8a08000    e8a08000    1861     15  13  0 Tiered-Slow

pDrives:
 ID ST T  V  NAME     PRODUCTID        REV  SECTORS     SECTORS     SIZE
                                            AVAIL       USED        GiB
 =======================================================================
 0  2  0  0  Drive1   ST2000DM006-2DM1 CC26 8b0         e8a08000    1863
```

under `tDrives` I don't know what status KO means or what the significance of "Promotes are turned off" is.

I also tried

```
PS C:\Program Files\AMD\StoreMI\ECmd> ecmd --convert t=0  single
Tdisk number 0 is failed, plug in missing drive to make it online
```

Questions:

1. Is the data on HDD1 lost? Can I recover the data?
2. If i provide a newly formatted SSD2 should I, in theory, be able to create a tier out of it using HDD1 with all the data in HDD1?
3. Any recommended course of actions here I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd in Administrator mode and copy the data:

```
ecmd --attach t=0 --force   <-forceattachment
```

May be needed if for any reason the fix involves help from the support teams and you prefer to always override the automatic dismount on error, the following option may allow the software to mount regardless of errors on subsequent reboots:

```
ecmd --loadonerror on t=0
```

However, I don't recommend it.